# How to connect my ASP.Net login code to MySQL database in VB.Net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I have designed a login with registration web page in ASP.Net using VB.NET but I want the new user to first register his/her details and the details to be stored in a MySQL database.

I have created a database in MySQL. I am failing to connect my Registration form to the database in MySQL.

Can someone assist with the connection code for ASP.Net in VB.Net to MySQL database?

Comment: What specifically have you tried so far and what errors are you running into?

Comment: failing how, exactly? We can't fix errors we can't see which occur in code we also can't see.

Comment: P.S. are you using ASP.NET Identity? (And if not, why not??). Maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider would help you

Comment: Hie Travis This is the code that i had done but its giving me some errors

Comment: Set up your connection string in the web.config, and then you can easily access that connection anywhere in the code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string

Comment: "giving me some errors" ..well then, what are they? Again, we can't guess fix errors if you don't tell us what they are and on which lines they occur.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that i have done but it is giving me errors.

```
Imports MySql.Data
Imports System.IO

Public Class Registration
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim strConn = "Server=localhost;database=Login;Uid =root;Pwd=;"
    Dim con As New MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
    Dim da As New MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter

    Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
        Dim User_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Password As String
        User_ID = TxtUserID.Text
        First_Name = TxtFacultyName.Text
        Last_Name = TxtLastName.Text
        First_Name = TxtEmail.Text
        First_Name = TxtPassword.Text

        Dim cmdtxt As String = Nothing
        cmdtxt = "Insert into Login(User_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Password ) " &
                     "Values('" & User_ID & "','" & First_Name & "', '" & Last_Name & "','" & Email & "','" & Password & "' ) "

        Try
            'The connection
            con.ConnectionString = strConn
            con.Open()


            'The OLEDB Command
            With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = cmdtxt
            End With

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MsgBox("Registration Successful", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Registration")
            TxtUserID.Clear()
            TxtFirstName.Clear()
             TxtLastName.Clear()
            TxtEmail.Clear()
             TxtPassword.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)

        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You said it's giving you errors.  Those errors are very important as they point to where the problem is.  So, please post the errors.

Comment: The first error is on the Imports MySql.Data  where it is saying the imports statement is not necessary(it doesnt contain any public member or cannot be found)

Comment: my declarations for the Connecter, Command and data adapter are all said to be not defined

Comment: Just an FYI: It is usually helpful to post the actual error, not your own interpretation. So when you debug, VS will display what the error was.  Post that.  But my guess is it's your actual connection string that you're declaring.  Did you look at the MSDN reference I posted above about how to set up the connection string?

Comment: And another tid-bit....your SQL query text is vulnerable to SQL injection. You're taking the value straight from the textbox, which is *not* a good idea at all.  Use parameters instead.

Comment: @John Peter i am going through the MSDN reference that you shared i will update once successful

Comment: Please don't post additional information in the Answers section. This isn't a solution to the problem. Please use the "edit" button (just under the blue "mysql" and "asp.net" tags at the bottom of your question) to add more details to your original post. The structure of this site is a Question-and-Answer format. It's not a discussion forum where you just post again and again in the same thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the connection string, see https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/

Keep all your database objects local so you can be sure they are closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks take care of this for you. You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the Connection. Likewise, you can pass the command text and the connection directly to the constructor of the Command.

Your UserID field should be an auto-number field (identity field) in the database. You do not include an auto-number fields in insert commands. For the other fields, use parameters to avoid Sql injection and make writing the sql statement easier. (no ampersands and double quotes and single quotes.

Open the connection at the last possible moment; right before the .Execute...

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
    Dim strSql = "Insert into Login(First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Password ) Values(@FName, @LName, @Email, @Password)"
    Try
        Using con As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;database=Login;Uid =root;Pwd=;"),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand(strSql, con)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@FName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TxtFacultyName.Text
                .Add("@LName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TxtLastName.Text
                .Add("@Email", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TxtEmail.Text
                .Add("@Password", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TxtPassword.Text
            End With
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using 'Closes and disposes the command and connection
        MsgBox("Registration Successful", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Registration")
        TxtUserID.Clear()
        TxtFirstName.Clear()
        TxtLastName.Clear()
        TxtEmail.Clear()
        TxtPassword.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Finally, **NEVER** store passwords as plain text. I will leave it to you to research salting and hashing of passwords and add this to the code.